# Cordova.js errors

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm getting the following errors when testing my app on chrome:

GET file:///www/cordova_plugins.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND            cordova.js:6189

OPTIONS file:///!gap_exec?1397986793096 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND       cordova.js:1034

deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.             cordova.js:5720
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady            cordova.js:5720
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady

People are asking similar questions, but I can't seem to get the error to go away.  Currently I'm developing on iOS and I am not using any plugins.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not test your application on chrome. cordova.js file will be embedded after building the project. try building and deploying your app on the device or emulator.

Comment: The app works fine on chrome, I just want to get rid of the errors.  The app also works on a device and an emulator but I won't be able to see these errors.  So by your answer are you saying that these errors can not be avoided if I'm testing the app on chrome?

Comment: yes exactly. but if you want to avoid these errors goto **/platforms** folder. after building the project all your files and a copy of cordova.js are there. if you open your applications main page form that folder you wont get file not found error. but you have to deal with deviceready event.

Comment: Alright thanks.  Thing about the cordova.js file is that I know for a fact it is located inside the project and I know I'm referencing it correctly, yet the errors persist.

Comment: the phonegap js file does not work in a browser. It's part of the phonegap framework that works in pair with native code for the devices

Comment: Alright fair enough.  As long as the app works on everything it's fine right?

Comment: Yes exactly. as long is you are not counting on ondeviceready event or other device specific features